# Error starting cassandra with brew , shows started in yellow

Tags: java, cassandra

I am trying to start cassandra with brew but on checking brew services, it shows started but in yellow, and doesnt work. How can I resolve this? My java version is 8, so it is not version issue. And I have deleted the commit logs from /usr/local/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog. What could be causing this issue ?

Comment: what is in the `system.log` file?

Comment: it doesnt show any recent logs. And i cleared the folder to generate new logs but not showing anything

Comment: try to start `cassandra -f` and see if it will start at all

Comment: yes it is starting as foreground service and able to access cqlsh. But how can I run it as background service? I guess brew abstracts a lot of things

Comment: I can't say that - I don't know how the brew packages Cassandra...